# how to get the onWindowFocusChanged on Fragment?

Tags: android, fragment

I am using [Android Sliding Menu using Navigation Drawer](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/).
I know that `onWindowFocusChanged` work on MainActivity.
How can I check is it hasFocus on Fragment?

someone said that I can pass the `hasFocus` to fragment, but I dont know how to do this. Can anyone give me some sample code?

I want to run ↓ this on my fragment

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    if (hasFocus) {
        //I need to do someing.
        method();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can either create an interface and all your fragments implement this interface, and inside your `onWindowFocusChanged` you get the current fragment and pass call the method provided by the interface.

A sample interface for the fragments could be:

```
public interface IOnFocusListenable {
   public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus);
}
```

Your fragments have to implement this interface:

```
public class MyFragment implements IOnFocusListenable {
    ....
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And in the `onWindowFocusChanged` of your Activity you can then do
the following:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override
   public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        if(currentFragment instanceof IOnFocusListenable) {
            ((IOnFocusListenable) currentFragment).onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Or you create a listener and the active fragment is added to the listener. So if the fragment is made visible you subscribe to this listener, and everytime the `onWindowFocusChanged`event is called you call this listener.

This approach is very similar to the above with the difference that there is a list of `IOnFocusListenable`'s and those are triggered in the activities `onWindowFocusChanged` method

Comment: Great answer, very helpful and neat!

Answer (score 51):

From **Android 4.3 (API 18)** and up you can use this code **directly in your Fragment**:

#### Kotlin

```kotlin
view?.viewTreeObserver?.addOnWindowFocusChangeListener { hasFocus -> /*do your stuff here*/ }
```

or define this extension in your project:

```kotlin
fun Fragment.addOnWindowFocusChangeListener(callback: (hasFocus: Boolean) -> Unit) =
    view?.viewTreeObserver?.addOnWindowFocusChangeListener(callback)
```

then simply call

```kotlin
addOnWindowFocusChangeListener { hasFocus -> /*do your stuff here*/ }
```

anywhere in your fragment (just be careful that the **root view** is still not null at that time).

#### Note: don't forget to remove your listener when you're done (removeOnWindowFocusChangeListener() method)!

---

#### Java

```java
getView().getViewTreeObserver().addOnWindowFocusChangeListener(hasFocus -> { /*do your stuff here*/ });
```

or without lambda:

```java
getView().getViewTreeObserver().addOnWindowFocusChangeListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnWindowFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(final boolean hasFocus) {
        // do your stuff here
    }
});
```

Where you can get the non-null **View** instance in the **onViewCreated()** method or simply call **getView()** from anywhere after that.

#### Note: don't forget to remove your listener when you're done (removeOnWindowFocusChangeListener() method)!