# How to cancel spinner mode dialog when touch outside of the dialog view

Tags: android, android-spinner

I couldn't find a solution on how to cancel the spinner mode dialog, by touching outside.

I know there's a method in dialog.cancle() in Dialog. But is there a way to cancel spinner mode dialog?

Thanks..

Comment: Anyone confronted like this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Created a custom spinner class, and override the following method:
Created a custom spinner class, and override the following method:

```
@Override
 public boolean performClick() {
 this.isDropDownMenuShown = true; //Flag to indicate the spinner menu is shown
 return super.performClick();
 }
```

In my Activity, override the method onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus). If hasFocus == true && the flag in #1 is set to true, then the spinner has been dismissed (can be either by selection or tapping outside the spinner).

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
if (actionBarSpinner.isDropdownShown() && hasFocus) {
    actionBarSpinner.setDropdownShown(false);
    //Do you work here
}
```

Comment: Can i use this inside Fragment?

Comment: You can implement onWindowFocusChanged in fragmnet by using this link... http://stackoverflow.com/a/30130065/4360419